# Get Field Value of DataRow that was right clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I go about extracting the value of a field in a DataGridViewRow, when a specific row has been right clicked (opening the ContextMenuStrip)?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code and explain what you see and what you expected to see.

Comment: Not getting you correctly. Do you mean adding the value retrieved to the ContextMenuStrip ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you talking about cell...If so use [CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) event, It has  DataGridViewCellEventArgs containing column and row indexes, they can be used to get value.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will set CurrentCell where you right click

```
private void grd_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
           DataGridView.HitTestInfo h =  grd.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
           if (h != null && h.RowIndex >= 0 && h.ColumnIndex >= 0)
           {
               grd.CurrentCell = grd[h.ColumnIndex, h.RowIndex];
               grd.ContextMenuStrip.Show(grd, e.Location);
           }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now when the ContextMenuStrip you have the value : `grd.CurrentCell.Value;`